# mongoose - save a record with multiple array of values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am a newbie to mongoose,
 have a mongoose schema like this :

```
var userSchema  =   new mongoose.Schema({
    username    : {type:String},
    password    : {type:String},
    firstName   : {type:String},
    lastName    : {type:String},
    email       : {type:String},
    userVerified: {type:String},
    userType    : {type:String},
    userGroup   : [
        {userRoles:{type:String}}
    ]
},{collection:'user'});
```

and data for the schema properties are received by using req.body.parameters, here i want to create a user record with multiple user roles at one time insertion.

what i have done is :

```
var userInfo    = {'username':username,'password':password,'firstName':firstName,'lastName':lastName,'email':email,'userVerified':userVerified,'userType':userType,'userGroup':{'userRoles':userGroup}}

    user(userInfo).save(function (err,doc){});
```

the inserted value looks like :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56ab511428f9f92f2b848845"), "username" : "kk", "password" : "dc468c70fb574ebd07287b38d0d0676d", "firstName" : "kk", "lastName" : "kk", "email" : "kk", "userVerified" : "1", "userType" : "user", "userGroup" : [ { "userRoles" : "[\"PHP\",\"NodeJS\"]", "_id" : ObjectId("56ab511428f9f92f2b848846") } ], "__v" : 0 }
```

and unwanted slashes are also in the array data.
help on this to be in correct way.
Thanks in advance

Comment: If `userGroup` is just an array of strings, consider changing its definition in the schema to just `userGroup: [String]`.

Comment: As you said, i have changed it, now the output is like :                   "userGroup" : [ "[\"PHP\",\"NodeJS\",\"Android\",\"Ios\",\"DotNet\"]" ] - why the slashes comes into the array, and how can i search the user who belonging the group for example "Ios"

Comment: So it looks like the `userGroup` variable is an array that contains _another_ array of strings instead of just being an array of strings. You don't show where that variable comes from, but using `userGroup[0]` instead would be one way to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set up your schema with a subdocument.

If you are wanting to set your userGroup property up as a Subdocument you would need to follow [this](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html). You would define a schema for userGroup separately:

```
var userGroup = new Schema({ {
  userRoles: {type: String}
}});

var userSchema  =   new Schema({
  username    : {type:String},
  password    : {type:String},
  firstName   : {type:String},
  lastName    : {type:String},
  email       : {type:String},
  userVerified: {type:String},
  userType    : {type:String},
  userGroup   : [userGroup]
},{collection:'user'});
```